# Display graph with ggplot in Shiny app with a function

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shinyapps

I'm doing right now a shiny web app, in order to plot some data that comes from csv files.

Here my code concerning the shiny app :

```
# install.packages("shiny")
library(shiny)
source("test.R")
# library(...) that I need


# User Interface
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Affichage de l'indice EPU"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Choix des paramètres"),
      selectInput("var", 
                  label = "Choisir une variable à afficher",
                  choices = list("Global", 
                                 "France",
                                 "Royaume-Uni"),
                  selected = "Percent White"),
      dateRangeInput("dateRange",
                     label = "Intervalle de temps : ",
                     format = "mm/yyyy",
                     language="fr",
                     start  = "2018-01-01",
                     end    = Sys.Date(),
                     startview = "year",
                     separator = " - ")
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("p")         
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$p <- renderPlot({
    graph_epu()

  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

For the moment, I don't use input in User Interface function, I just want to plot the data.
My function, inside the file test.R, do some things in order to generate a graph.
Here my function :

```
graph_epu <- function(){
  
  # On importe les données du csv dans les dataframes
  df_lesechos <- read.csv(file = "data/df_lesechos.csv", sep=",")
  df_latribune <- read.csv(file = "data/df_latribune.csv", sep=",")
  
  # On supprime le jour pour le remplacer par 01
  df_lesechos$Date <- substr(df_lesechos$Date,1,7)
  df_latribune$Date <- substr(df_latribune$Date,1,7)
  df_lesechos$Date <- paste(df_lesechos$Date,"-01",sep="")
  df_latribune$Date <- paste(df_latribune$Date,"-01",sep="")
  
  
  
  # Transforme la colonne Occurences au format numérique
  #df_lesechos <- transform(df_lesechos, Occurences = as.numeric(Occurences))
  #df_latribune <- transform(df_latribune, Occurences = as.numeric(Occurences))
  
  
  
  df_lesechos$Occurences <- as.numeric(df_lesechos$Occurences)
  df_latribune$Occurences <- as.numeric(df_latribune$Occurences)
  

  # On convertit la colonne date au format Date
  df_lesechos <- transform(df_lesechos, Date = as.Date(Date))
  df_latribune <- transform(df_latribune, Date = as.Date(Date))
  
  # On élimine les valeurs datant d'avant 2018
  df_lesechos <- df_lesechos[!(df_lesechos$Date < "2018-01-01"),]
  df_latribune <- df_latribune[!(df_latribune$Date < "2018-01-01"),]
  
  # On groupe par mois et on fait la somme des occurences
  df_lesechos <- df_lesechos %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarise(Occurences = sum(Occurences)) %>% arrange(desc(Date))
  df_latribune <- df_latribune %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarise(Occurences = sum(Occurences)) %>% arrange(desc(Date))
  
  # Calcul de la variance pour chaque journal
  echos_var <- var(df_lesechos$Occurences)
  tribune_var <- var(df_latribune$Occurences)
  
  # Divisions des occurences par l'écart type, ce qui nous donne un écart type unitaire
  df_lesechos$Occurences <- (df_lesechos$Occurences) / sqrt(echos_var)
  df_latribune$Occurences <- (df_latribune$Occurences) / sqrt(tribune_var)
  
  # La normalisation de chaque série mensuelles des différents journaux nous permets de les combiner
  # Création du dataframe qui va faire la somme des deux dataframes
  df_france <- bind_rows(df_lesechos,df_latribune)
  df_france <- df_france %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarise(Occurences = sum(Occurences)) %>% arrange(desc(Date))
  
  # On divise par 2 la série obtenue car on a 2 sources d'informations
  df_france$Occurences <- df_france$Occurences / 2
  
  # Calcul de la moyenne de la série 
  moyenne <- mean(df_france$Occurences)
  
  # On ramène la série à une moyenne de 100 afin d'obtenir l'indicateur EPU de chaque mois
  df_france$Occurences <- df_france$Occurences*(100/moyenne)
  
  # Visualisation de la série à l'aide ggplot2
  p <- df_france %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=Date, y=Occurences, text = paste0("Date : ", format(Date, "%Y-%m"), "\n",
                                                   "EPU : ", round(Occurences)))) +
    geom_area(fill="#5685D7", alpha=0.5, group=1) +
    geom_line(color="#FF0000", size=0.2, group=1) +
    ggtitle("FR Indice EPU") +
    ylab("EPU") +
    xlab("Années-Mois") +
    geom_point(size=0.5) +
    scale_x_date(breaks = df_france$Date, labels = date_format("%Y-%m")) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
          plot.title = element_text(size=14, face="italic", family="Avenir Next"),
          axis.title.x = element_text(family="Avenir Next"),
          axis.title.y = element_text(family="Avenir Next"))
  
  p <- ggplotly(p, tooltip = "text")
  p
  
}
```

The object p is the graph.
i really don't know how to proceed in order to display the graph. When I run the app, only the sidebar is display, and there is no graph. I have any errors in the consol...

If someone can help me, it would be really great.

Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: I think you have to use renderPlotly and poltlyOutput to output plotly graph

Answer (score 0):

Reading in the csv files on the server side might help.  Try this

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # On importe les données du csv dans les dataframes 
  df_lesechosi <- read.csv(file = "data/df_lesechos.csv", sep=",")
  df_latribunei <- read.csv(file = "data/df_latribune.csv", sep=",")
  
  mygraph <- reactive({
    graph_epu(df_lesechos=df_lesechosi, df_latribune=df_latribunei)
  })
  
  output$p <- renderPlotly({
    mygraph()
  })
}

### Your function should be as follows, and no need to read in csv files within this function
graph_epu <- function(df_lesechos="", df_latribune=""){...
```